# the following packages have unmet dependencies(KDE)

Tags: apt, dependencies

I'm new to Ubuntu but I failed to solve this error. I had searched for this problem but I didn't find the perfect solution. Please help me. I'm finding this error. Please give me a perfect solution because this error doesn't let me to install any software. The error is:

```
the following packages have unmet dependencies:

software-properties-kde: Depends: python3 (>= 3.2.3-3~) but 3.3.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                         Depends: python3-pyqt4 but it is not going to be installed"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the launchpad error, have you tried changing the selected 'other software' in Software Updater?

It's probably been selected by some program as a source there, so uncheck entries that refer to launchpad.

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal and issue this command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: i get it solved by changing sources.list but got now new error.Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/xampp/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: It may be outdated link.